# Postgres psycopg2: Relation/Table not saved after closing connection

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to create a table that logs my app in postgresql. Below works well.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="db1", user = "postgres", password = "", host = "myhost", port = "5432")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE login
      (USERNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      TS TIMESTAMP);''')
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO public.login (USERNAME,TS) \
      VALUES ('TEST','2019-12-03')""");
my_table    = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM public.login', conn)
conn.close()
```

I thought the table/relation would have been created and saved. But when I reconnect I get error that `UndefinedTable: relation "public.login" does not exist`.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="db1", user = "postgres", password = "", host = "myhost", port = "5432")
print ("Opened database successfully")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO public.login (USERNAME,TS) \
      VALUES ('TEST','2019-12-03')""");
my_table    = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM public.login', conn)
```

The table is not there with below, as answered in [How do I get tables in postgres using psycopg2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598002/how-do-i-get-tables-in-postgres-using-psycopg2)

```
cur.execute("""SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
       WHERE table_schema = 'public'""")
for table in cur.fetchall():
    print(table)
```

I am confused why closing connection would cause this.

Comment: try `conn.commit()` before `conn.close()`?

Answer (score 0):

You must call `conn.commit()`..