Python subprocess run hanging with psql result in kubernetes pod
I'm trying to get a list of databases from a Kubernetes pod.
This works and databases are printed in the terminal:
 result = subprocess.run(['kubectl', '--context', 'my-context', '-n', 'mynamespace', 'exec', '-it', 'postgres-helper-58dc64d7f4-cmkxl', '--', '/bin/bash', '-c', 'psql postgresql://postgres:password@postgres-postgresql --list --quiet --tuples-only'], check=true)


 mydb1     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | 
 mydb2     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             |            |                 | postgres=CTc/postgres

However, I need to capture this output:
result = subprocess.run(['kubectl', '--context', 'my-context', '-n', 'mynamespace', 'exec', '-it', 'postgres-helper-58dc64d7f4-cmkxl', '--', '/bin/bash', '-c', 'psql postgresql://postgres:password@postgres-postgresql --list --quiet --tuples-only'], check=true, capture_output=True)

Adding capture_output=True makes the command hang.
If I log in to the pod:
root@postgres-helper-58dc64d7f4-cmkxl:/# ps aux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
postgres       1  0.0  0.1 220936 27904 ?        Ss   11:10   0:00 postgres
postgres      62  0.0  0.0 221060  9452 ?        Ss   11:10   0:00 postgres: checkpointer 
postgres      63  0.0  0.0 221072  7020 ?        Ss   11:10   0:00 postgres: background writer 
postgres      65  0.0  0.0 220936 10220 ?        Ss   11:10   0:00 postgres: walwriter 
postgres      66  0.0  0.0 222516  8940 ?        Ss   11:10   0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher 
postgres      67  0.0  0.0 222500  8172 ?        Ss   11:10   0:00 postgres: logical replication launcher 
root          96  0.0  0.0  23556 11136 pts/0    Ss+  11:24   0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin/psql postgresql://postgres:password@postgres-postgresql --list --quiet --tuples-only
root         102  0.0  0.0   2320  1280 pts/0    S+   11:24   0:00 sh -c pager
root         103  0.0  0.0   5516  2048 pts/0    S+   11:24   0:00 pager
root         104  0.0  0.0   7064  3584 pts/1    Ss   11:24   0:00 bash
root       

  320  0.0  0.0  10996  4096 pts/1    R+   11:25   0:00 ps aux

The process is sitting there, perhaps waiting for some input that I can't figure out.
Note: I need to connect to a postgres service in another pod, so I need to execute psql -h.

Can you try to connect its stdin to something, like input="", or perhaps nothing stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL?

@tripleee this works. Does that mean the process is waiting for input of some kind?

Apparently yes (-:

Is the client also running in the cluster?  Can you use an ordinary PostgreSQL client library like psycopg2, instead of trying to do this via shell commands?

Do yo mean something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24462829/908773, that could work, but I'm having trouble passing the command to subprocess when trying to escape the quotes.
